# +CMS ERROR: invalid parameter

Tags: gsm, at-command, modem, telecommunication

I have connected a GSM modem to my computer. When the application  sent message, getting below response. i have replaced the mobile number in log file with xxxxxxxx. Application was able to sent SMS, but this issue started all of a sudden.

> 2017-01-16 06:40:09,217 | INFO  | PagerChannel.java |
>   PagerChannel::sendSMS (single message) ENTER
>
> 2017-01-16 06:40:09,217 | INFO  | PagerChannel.java | Connecting on
>   Port:com3 with boud rate:115200
>
> 2017-01-16 06:40:19,289 | INFO  | PagerChannel.java | Connected on
>   Port:com3 with boud rate:115200
>
> 2017-01-16 06:40:19,811 | INFO  | PagerChannel.java | Sending SMS on :
>   xxxxxxxx using AT^SCMS=xxxxxxxx,145,1,5,16,2088
>
> 2017-01-16 06:40:19,871 | ERROR | PagerChannel.java |
>   PagerChannel.sendSMS Error response: for
>   AT^SCMS=xxxxxxxx,145,1,5,16,2088 response:
>
> +CMS ERROR: invalid parameter

Can Anybody tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue which was causing the error, these issue started when i changed the mobile number format to just the number without country code. (from +974MobileNumber to MobileNumber)

In that scenario the Type of Destination Address value should 129 , but in my case it was using the 145.

**AT^SCMS=da[toda], seq, max, ieia, ref**

> Type of Destination Address GSM 04.11 TP-Destination-Address
>   Type-of-Address octet in integer format (when first character of 
>   is + (IRA 43) default is 145, otherwise default is 129).